# How to use Scrapy to recursively scroll through a news page with a 'show more' button

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I am very new to web scraping and I have a specific problem for a social sciences project. I'm trying to crawl the bbc news blog (https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs/the_papers), open up every article and search for the incidence of a word. My spider looks like this so far:

```
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'news_spider'

start_urls = ['https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs/the_papers']

data_array = []

def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('news blog data:')
    news_blogs = response.css('div.blog__story.story-inner')

    for blog in news_blogs:
        link = blog.css('a::attr(href)').get()
        data_point = blog_parser(link, 'immigration')
        self.logger.info(link)
        self.logger.info(data_point.showData())
        yield {
            'text': blog.css('span.cta::text').get()
        }
```

This scraper works for the first page of the website. My problem is I need to click the 'more stories' button at the bottom of the page and recursively scrape the new data as many times as possible. To do this I know I need to mimic the request made when clicking on the [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ptn.png)

Every time the more stories button is clicked there is an xhr request of the form: https://www.bbc.com/news/ssi/components.html?batch[blog][opts][asset_id]=blogs/the_papers&before=x

But there is no pattern I could recursively replicate, by that I mean the first parameter x is 1583453829, the next is 1582674398, and so on, with no discernible pattern. I haven't been able to find a tutorial that teaches me how to deal with this type of situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig in the response of every XHR request with form https://www.bbc.com/news/ssi/components.html?batch[blog][opts][asset_id]=blogs/the_papers&before=x , you can find an element at the beginning of the response like this:

```
<div class="blog__stories story-body" id="comp-blog" data-next="/news/ssi/components.html?batch[blog][opts][asset_id]=blogs/the_papers&before=1583796820" >
```

the value of the `data-next` attribute is what you want to make the next request.